# computing $29^{25}$ (mod 11)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I'm trying to learn how to use Fermat's Little Theorem.

$29=2\cdot11+7 \Rightarrow 11\nmid29$

by the theorem we have $29^{10}\equiv 1$(mod 11)

$25=10\cdot 2 + 5$

$ 29^{25}=(29^{10})^2\cdot29^5\equiv 29^5$(mod 11)

where do I go from here?

Comment: $29=-4\mod 11$. $2^5=32=-1\mod 11$, $(-4)^5=-2^52^5=-1\mod 11$.

Answer (score 3):

$$29^{25}\equiv(-4)^{25}\equiv(-4)^{-5}\equiv(-3)^{5}\equiv-27\cdot9\equiv(-5)(-2)\equiv10\quad(\text{mod }11)$$
I use the theorem in the second step and the third step works because $3\cdot4\equiv1\ (\text{mod }11)$.